# data.table fast table search

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset that can be filtered in multiple dimensions, and was wondering if there was a fast way to do that filtering...

To give a bit of background I have 6 dimensions of differing sizes, to represent the data I have made a mock grid in R but with the last dimension being made a bit smaller so that it fits into RAM.

```
d1 <- 3
d2 <- 6
d3 <- 24
d4 <- 7
d5 <- 12
d6 <- 10000 # my actual dataset is actually 500000

full.DT <- data.table(expand.grid(h1=seq(d1),
                                  h2=seq(d2),
                                  h3=seq(d3),
                                  h4=seq(d4),
                                  h5=seq(d5),
                                  h6=seq(d6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
# each permutation and combination produces a specific score...
# which I am mimicking using the runif function
full.DT[,score:=runif(nrow(full.DT))]
```

I would like to filter it for 2000 unique values of `h6`, and for a single value of `h2`. Currently I am doing it using the lines below....but feel that its a bit slow and definitely wont scale when using my true value of `d6` of 500000.

It is currently taking 32 seconds on OSX 10.10.3, with 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. Would using keys help? are there ways of speeding this up? and also are there any methods of dealing with the object size vs size of RAM issue, (perhaps by splitting up the data into separate tables that get read in separately)? is C++ a potential answer?

```
 no.unique.h6.vals <- 2000
 h2.val <- 1
 chosen.h6.vals <- sample.int(d6,no.unique.h6.vals)

 system.time(ff <- full.DT[(h6 %in% chosen.h6.vals) & (h2==h2.val),])
    user  system elapsed 
  15.600   9.571  31.661
```

Also although this is one type of filter... on the data I would ideally like to have the flexibility to filter it on any of the given dimensions, e.g. a specific value for `h3`, `h4` and `h5` etc (e.g.)...

```
x <- 10000
h1 <- sample.int(d1,x,replace=TRUE)
h2 <- sample.int(d2,x,replace=TRUE)
h3 <- sample.int(d3,x,replace=TRUE)
h4 <- sample.int(d4,x,replace=TRUE)
h5 <- sample.int(d5,x,replace=TRUE)
h6 <- sample.int(d6,x,replace=TRUE)

g.full <- data.table(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6)
```

and then filtering on all the g.full rows...

***Edit***

As per David Arenberg's comments

running the following line...

```
setkey(full.DT, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6)
```

seems to help in terms of speed....

```
system.time(ff3 <- full.DT[data.table(expand.grid(h1=seq(d1),h2=h2.val,h3=seq(d3),h4=seq(d4),h5=seq(d5),h6=chosen.h6.vals,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),])

  user  system elapsed 
 2.762   0.420   3.182
```

And which also helps for the other situations too:

```
 system.time(ff4 <- full.DT[g.full])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.031   0.055
```

This seems very fast...are there any potential solutions to the RAM problem?

Comment: With your example, I get an empty "ff".

Comment: @Pascal that's probably because OP doesn't even have a `d2` column

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right.

Comment: I'm guessing `d2` is `h2`. One could try `setkey(full.DT, h6, h2) ; system.time(ff2 <- full.DT[.(chosen.h6.vals, d2.val)])`

Comment: Appologies that has now been corrected...

Comment: Have you tried using binary search as per my comment above? You will need to switch `d2.val` with `h2.val` as per your edit.

Comment: Why does the question have a tag `rcpp` ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel OP is hoping someone will provide him a `rcpp` solution which will be faster than the `data.table` one.

Comment: "Begging for code" is a reason to close ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel rcpp tag removed...

Comment: I cannot store such a thing in RAM myself, but I'm pretty sure the answer is: use an `array`. They can go up to six dimensions, sure. My cursory examination suggests that your `expand.grid` will not fit in RAM on any computer: `object.size(do.call(expand.grid,lapply(c(7,12,500000),seq))) # 526 MB`, so maybe you need to be less generous towards `d6`.

Comment: Or, if possible, partition `d6` and repeat the process